# Synonyms in Bot framework V4 no longer work

Tags: botframework

The synonym feature in the bot framework is not working as intended. With the following line of code it should result in value = "Create new case" if the use enter new/new case. So far only create new case will go to the right dialog while new case/new will result in the bot not understand what the user wants.

```
private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> ChoiceCardStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext step, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Create options for the prompt
            Activity activity = step.Context.Activity;
            var options = new PromptOptions()
            {
                Prompt = activity.CreateReply("What would you like to do?"),
                Choices = new List<Choice>(),
            };


            // Add the choices for the prompt.
            options.Choices.Add(new Choice() { Value = "Check case status" , Synonyms = new List<string> { "status", "case status", "check case" }});
            options.Choices.Add(new Choice() { Value = "Create new case" , Synonyms = new List<string> { "new", "new case" } });
            options.Choices.Add(new Choice() { Value = "Look for an agent" });
            options.Choices.Add(new Choice() { Value = "End Conversation" });

            return await step.PromptAsync("cardPrompt", options, cancellationToken);
        }



`WaterfallStep[] steps = new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                ChoiceCardStepAsync,
                HandleChoiceAsync,
                LoopBackAsync,
            }

        _dialogs = new DialogSet(_accessors.DialogStateAccessor)
            .Add(new WaterfallDialog(MainDialogId, steps))
            .Add(new CheckCaseStatusDialog(CheckCaseStatusDialogId))
            .Add(new NewCaseDialog(NewCaseDialogId))
            .Add(new ChoicePrompt("cardPrompt") {Style = ListStyle.SuggestedAction });`
```

I've check on the microsoft documentation and it is still available for bot framework V4 but I'm not sure why it does not have effect. Anyone can enlighten me on what I'm missing?

Comment: This should work. Can you please show the code that creates your prompt and the code that invokes it (i.e. `PromptAsync`)?

Comment: I've updated the post with the whole method

Comment: Be great to see the code that creates the cardPrompt too.

Comment: added. the bottom code is from constructor. @DrewMarsh

Comment: Please add the HandleChoiceAsync logic